# What does the toJSON method do on the XML class?

Tags: xml, json, actionscript-3

I saw this method today on the XML class. I need to convert XML to JSON but this method only returns "XML".

Here is a code example:

```
var s = new XML().toJSON('<bob a="10"><sue name="sue"></bob>');
trace(s); // "XML"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html) for complete documentation.

Below I've included the important documentation snippet provided by Adobe.

XML:

```
toJSON(k:String):*
Provides an overridable method for customizing the JSON encoding of values in an XML object.
```

All in all, `new Xml(myXml).toJSON()` provides a means to convert the XML formatted string to JSON format. 
In order to convert the XML to JSON successfully, the **developer must override this method and provide an appropriate implementation.**

You XML reads:

```
<bob a="10"><sue name="sue"></bob>
```

The `sue` tag is not closed properly, thus your XML is invalid.

Comment: I fixed the xml and it still returned the class name. By default the method only returns the class name which is "XML". Developers still need to add their own implementation. Add this to your answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: What do you think is the point of adding a method that does nothing in itself and is only meant to be overridden? Is it there just for abstract purposes?

Comment: I fully imagine if we could see the Flash source there would be a great big //TODO in this function.

Comment: @Glitcher - :). Interestingly enough, before posting the question I searched online and found this, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652200. Was still confused which is why I posted the original question. Does that page answer any questions or lead to more???